# PHP MYSQL query is not passing the array into my variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

Here is my query and it's coming up with $results as NULL when I do a var_dump:

```
function connect($loginName) {
$password = (isset($_SESSION['password']));
$loginName = (isset($_SESSION['loginName']));

global $db;
$query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email   = '$loginName'";
$result = $db->query($query);
$results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $results;
}
```

After attempting changes suggested it is giving me these two errors in my welcome form:

[image: Errors in WElcome section of my website]

FUNCTIONS PAGE:

```
<?php 
require('database_connection.php');
//include('index.php')
//session_start();
if ((isset($_POST['loginName'])) && (isset($_POST['password']))){
  $_SESSION['loginName'] = $_POST['loginName'];
  $_SESSION['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$password = isset($_SESSION['password']) ? $_SESSION['password'] : "";
$loginName = isset($_SESSION['loginName']) ? $_SESSION['loginName'] : "";


// Connecting to the database
 }

function connect($loginName) {

 global $db;
$query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email = '$loginName'";
$result = $db->query($query);
$results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $results;
}


//Login

function login($loginName, $password) {
$results = connect($loginName);
if ((isset($_SESSION['loginName'])) === $results['email'] && (isset    ($_SESSION['password'])) === $results['password']) 
 {

if ( 'a' === $results['level'] )  {
$level = "Administrator";
 } 
elseif ( 'm' === $results['level'] ) {
 $level = "Member";
}
else $level = '?';

if ($level === "Administrator"){
        header('Location: /tires/admin/home.php');
        exit();
    }elseif ($level === "Member"){
        header('Location: /tires/member/home.php');
        exit();
    }                           
include('logoutform.php');}



else {

echo "Sorry. You are not in our database";

}};



//Trying to verify the password

 if ((isset($_POST['loginName'])) && (isset($_POST['password']))){
  $_SESSION['loginName'] = $_POST['loginName'];
  $_SESSION['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}
$password = (isset($_SESSION['password']));
 $loginName = (isset($_SESSION['loginName']));
 $hash = '';

global $db;
$h = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE email = '$loginName'");
$h->execute();
$hashing = $h->fetchAll();
foreach ($hashing as $hash) {
    return $hash['password'];
    if($hashing) // will return true if succefull else it will return false 
        { 
            echo 'Query is working';// code here for true
        };
 };

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
 };




//Logout
function logout() {
$_SESSION = array();
 session_destroy();
 };


 function get_name($results) {
$name = preg_split("/@/", $results['email']);
$name = ucfirst($name[0]);
 return $name;
                        };



function allowed_get_params($allowed_params=[]) {
 $allowed_array = [];
    foreach($allowed_params as $param) {
        if(isset($_GET[$param])) {
            $allowed_array[$param] = $_GET[$param];
        } else {
            $allowed_array[$param] = NULL;
    }
    }
    return $allowed_array;
 };

 $get_params = allowed_get_params(['loginName', 'password']);


?>
```

AND, This is the login (logout really) form:

```
 <form method="post" id="logoutform.php">

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Logout</legend>  

                      <?php
 //include('includes/functions.php');
                       //if ( $_SESSION['loginName'] === $result['email']      && $_SESSION['password'] === $result['password']) {
               echo "Welcome, ";
               echo "$level, ";
               echo get_name($results); 
              // print_r($_POST);
               print '<br />';
               //}
              // else{
            //var_dump($result);
          ///}
                      ?>  <br />   <br />  <br />     
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="logout" />

 </fieldset></form>
```

THe LOGIN FORM is this one:

```
<form action="home.php" method="post" id="loginform.inc.html">
<fieldset>

  <legend>Login</legend>    <label for="loginName" class="loginName">Username:</label>
      <input id="loginName" name="loginName" type="text" value="<?php echo     (isset($loginName['loginName'])); ?>"/>
    <label for="password" class="loginName">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo (isset($password['password'])); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
</fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: show your full code .. there is no level variable and get_name function in above code

Comment: Oh, in looking at your edits, it seems you have several problems.  Forget the results coming back as null.  You have all sorts of other issues here.  post logoutform.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$password = (isset($_SESSION['password']));
$loginName = (isset($_SESSION['loginName']));
```

to

```
$password = isset($_SESSION['password']) ? $_SESSION['password'] : "";
$loginName = isset($_SESSION['loginName']) ? $_SESSION['loginName'] : "";
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't help - Thank you so much for trying though. God bless you.

Comment: do a `die("login name: $loginName");` right after `$loginName = (isset($_SESSION['loginName']));` and see if you even have the login name stored in the session as you expect.

Comment: Yes, I'll post my functions page and more if you like. Thank you for helping. It's still not logging in, just throws the error.

Comment: the code is really messy! lol. Can you please `var_dump($query);` after your sql statement. and tell me what you got

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: query in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tires\admin\home.php on line 58
NULL  - although, I can change some code around in the login and it will sometimes say Welcome, ERROR for Level, and the name??? Weird. I can't figure it out. It's got me really stumped. I APPRECIATE your help.

Comment: undefined query???? you just declared it in the line above. Are you placing the `var_dump` after `$query="...."` ?

Comment: I can't get the var_dump to show up anywhere when I place it just after the function? Could you explain? Sorry - I'm a learner, though. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71944/discussion-between-regina-shepherd-riddle-and-lea-tano).

Comment: Sorry i went to sleep. Sure i would like to help you. Ee can discus it in chat

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `$results` is empty because your query is not returning anything.  And I suspect your query is not returning anything, because you're doing a search for the `$loginName` of `TRUE` (or maybe `FALSE`), because of this line:

```
$loginName = (isset($_SESSION['loginName']));
```

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns true or false. I suspect that's not what you want.

It's also unclear what your `global $db` is about. I hope that's psuedo code. If that is your literal code, then you have a clear bug in that you aren't even attempting to connect to the database.

Also, you should be passing the login name using a paramaterized statement to avoid an [obvious security hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: This code was working and stopped when I added more code to go from member to admin pages. Would you like to see that code? So far, nothing is working.

Comment: Flimzy explained the problem perfectly.  And Lea Tano provided the solution, which corresponds to this explanation.